# How to do math with an array (add +1)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a value in an input like this:

```
7*7*0*0*32*17
```

I do a simple .split('*') to obtain the following arrays:

```
["7","7","0","0","32","17"]
```

Then I transform the arrays into numbers with .map(Number), so the arrays are now composed not of strings but numbers:

```
[7,7,0,0,32,17]
```

What interests me is the second 7. I use a .slice(1,2) in order to select it alone. Until that point, it works:

```
[7]
```

My problem is, I can't add +1 to transform the 7 into a 8. Instead, it returns 71.

Let's call the array of ["7","7","0","0","32","17"] -> "myArray" to simplify the whole stuff.

```
console.log(myArray);
var myArrayMapped = myArray.map(Number);
console.log(myArrayMapped);
var myArraySliced = myArrayMapped.slice(1,2);
console.log(myArraySliced);
var myArrayIncreased = myArraySliced + 1;
console.log(myArrayIncreased);
```

And here will be the results of the console.logs:

```
["7","7","0","0","32","17"]
[7,7,0,0,32,17]
[7]
71
```

Everything works as expected up until this line, which doesn't work:

```
var myArrayIncreased = myArraySliced + 1;
```

Note that my final goal is to put back the 8 inside the input, and reconstruct the array into one single string like below, so maybe there's a simplier and faster solution I haven't seen. Basically, a button will call a function to add +1 to the very specific part of value I want to select (the second "7"):

From:

```
7*7*0*0*32*17
```

To:

```
7*8*0*0*32*17
```

Thanks in advance. Note that I do not want to sum up all the arrays, nor push a new array among the ones I got (which are the topics I've seen through my research, which don't help me). I just want to do maths with one specific array.

Comment: Do you want to fix the typos in your code?

Comment: `var ["7","7","0","0","32","17"] = myArray;` -> `Uncaught SyntaxError:...`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't have `var ["7","7","0","0","32","17"] = myArray;` straight in my code. I just simplified it roughly, so you know what I'm working from. If it bothers you, just consider `myArray` returns `["7","7","0","0","32","17"]`.

Comment: You chose to illustrate the problem with pseudo-code to show us the code? Fair enough, that seems needlessly complex (and a little pointless), but...okay.

Comment: Again, the goal was to make it way simpler to understand. But if it's such a deal no problem, I removed that line ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `slice`, you could select it with it's array index

```
myArrayMapped[1] += 1;
```

which would make the final code

```
var myArray = ["7","7","0","0","32","17"];
console.log(myArray);
var myArrayMapped = myArray.map(Number);
console.log(myArrayMapped);
myArrayMapped[1] += 1;
console.log(myArrayMapped);
```

Comment: Avoiding the .slice() is actually not bad and will probably help for next steps, thanks :)

Comment: @Orphal I find avoiding `slice` & accessing via index more helpful most of the time :)

Answer (score 2):

You are not adding one to 7, you are adding one to an array that has a single index.

```
var myArrayIncreased = myArraySliced + 1;
//var myArrayIncreased = [7] + 1;
```

If you want to do the addition, you need to use the first index

```
var myArrayIncreased = myArraySliced[0] + 1;
//var myArrayIncreased = 7 + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `[7]` with 1 
instead of `7` with 1

```
[7]+1 = '71'
```

After get your numeric array sliced and get [7], you should refer to the element's content which should look:

```
var myArrayIncreased = myArraySliced.map(function(n){return n+1});
console.log(myArrayIncreased);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
var myArrayIncreased = 1*myArraySliced + 1;
```